# Partition missing and showing as empty in disk management

Tags: partitioning

I’m in a very bad situation where one of my partition got deleted and it’s showing empty in disk management. Here is what happened.

I had Windows 7 already and I needed another windows 7. There was 3 partitions in my PC. `C:`, `D:` and `E:` with data in it. I shrink the `E:` Volume with a partition the utility (because disk management wasn’t allowing  me to and showed I have maximum number of partitions). So with that utility, I created a 16 GB logical partition and then installed Windows 7 in that partition. After that when the new OS is loaded, I can't see my old `D:` drive anymore.

New OS partition became `C:`, old windows partition (`C:`) became `D:` and `E:` stayed the same. But old `D:` is gone. When I checked in disk management, I can see the space and it shows fully empty. No drive letter is assigned. Right click gives only one option: Create new volume. So what should I do? Is data gone forever and data recover software only option? I tried test disk and it’s showing 4 partitions.

I don’t understand which partition should I select. I don’t want to lose any more data and don't want to lose any chance of getting back that `D:` drive. So please help. What should I do?

Comment: Before installing the new Windows 7, did you do anything to your D drive? if not then is it possible that you just deleted the D drive when installing new Windows 7? because a drive can't be deleted/removed by itself.

Comment: no. nothing.. D drive wasn't even touched. all this happened after windows install, I people having similar problem but most of them have a deleted partition with unallocated space. but my case is little different. the partition is not showing as unallocated but it's asking to create a new volume. and no. it wasn't touched during windows install. I clearly remember it..I only selected that 16 GB partition and it was already formatted. so never did any formatting

Comment: I don't understand how you don't have any unallocated space but it asks you to create a new volume. it is also possible that because your disk is basic and it only allows you to have 3 partitions, the software you used deleted your D drive and instead created a new 16 GB drive.

Comment: to answer your question, that's the problem. that 100+ GB d drive is not marked as unallocated. the only option available in right click is 'create new volume' and it's showing completely empty.

Comment: Not sure why no one has suggested you look at testdisk and photorec - testdisk may be useful in recovering your partition (maybe), and photorec may be useful as a last ditch effort to salvage data in a drive where the partions/filsystem is fried.  They are part of the same suite of free tools.

Comment: This was posted as an edit.  I'm re-posting here pending OP creating an answer: The problem is solved and I got my partition back(with full data). I used AOEMI partiton assistant and it successfully recovered my lost partition.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your data is currently gone. what has happened is that the software you used for partitioning has created another primary partition for you with a size of 16 GB and removed your D drive. i think that your disk type is simple

> because disk management wasn't allowing me to and showed I have maximum number of partitions

which means you are only allowed to have 3 primary partitions and 1 extended partition (in a [MBR disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)). your D drive must appear in Disk management as 'free space'. the only option left for you is to create the 4th partition in disk management as the extended partition, once you're done, you can use recovery software to get all your data back. most recovery programs have an option for deleted/formatted volumes. to recommend some, i personally use [recover my files](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/) and it recovers all files from a formatted volume. of course there are many other alternatives and even free programs.